# Jquery's index() function returns -1 instead of clicked list items position in his parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

Every time i try to use this once my list item is clicked, it returns -1.
Can someone enlighten me? I'd appreciate it :/ Thank you. Here is what i've been doing, need to create an image slider with thumbnails.

```
function create_thumbs() {
    imagesUl.children('li').each(function() {
        $('<li class="thumbs"><img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb"/></li>').addClass('thumb').hide().appendTo('ul#thumbs').fadeIn(300)
        .click(function() {
            goToSlide();
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

That is a function to creat thumbnails for each image i have in the slideshow. Below is the start of the function i will create to go to the corresponding image after the thumb is clicked.

```
function goToSlide() {
    var thumbClicked = $(this);
    alert(thumbClicked.parent('ul#thumbs').index());
}
```

Alert always returns -1. I tried couple of ways. What could be the problem ?

Since someone asked for some html, here it is, the only thing important to the issue :

```
<div id="slider">
                    <ul id="images">
                        <li><img src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="1" title="1"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="2" title="2"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/slideshow/3.jpg" alt="3" title="3"/></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="thumbs">

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you have some HTML or better make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: You seem to be looking for the index of the parent `ul#thumbs` which is, presumably, the same for all of your thumbnails (since they are appended to the same parent). I'm assuming that isn't what you wanted? Shouldn't it be just `thumbClicked.index()`? (after fixing your `this` problem)

Comment: thumbClicked.index() on it's own returns the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in the goToSlide function is the global scope, `window`. You can set the execution context explicitly using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
goToSlide.call(this);
```

Alternatively you can pass the element you clicked on as an argument:

```
goToSlide(this);
....
function goToSlide(thumbClicked){
    alert(thumbClicked.parent('ul#thumbs').index());
}
```

Comment: I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'parent' when i try this way :/

Comment: @Novica89 jQuery sets the browser's HtmlElement as the execution context (`this`) but the `parent` function is only defined for jQuery objects. Use $(this) to turn convert the HtmlElement to a jQuery object.

Comment: Thank you all, i managed to get to the source of the problem ! :) The parent wasnt directly main UL but the li inside of it, since I used spans for creating thumbs and because of that it always showed -1. Now everything is working ,but wouldnt be that way if your answer wasnt here, since i would be in trouble for refering to the global window instead for the item that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

always try to post a minimum version to http://jsfiddle.net/ to make it easier for us to help you. Also read up on http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/25/this-binding/

try this

```
function create_thumbs() {
    imagesUl.children('li').each(function() {
        $('<li class="thumbs"><img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb"/></li>').addClass('thumb').hide().appendTo('ul#thumbs').fadeIn(300)
        .click(function() {
            goToSlide($(this));
            return false;
        });
    });
}

function goToSlide(thumbClicked) {
    alert(thumbClicked.parent('ul#thumbs').index());
}
```